# Email de confirmação de registo com Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Estou a tentar utilizar o método `sendEmailVerification()` do `Firebase` após o registo do usuário através do *Login* por e-mail. O meu problema é que não me aparece a opção de usar esse método após criar o usuario na base de dados através do `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`.

Estou a usar a versão 9.0.2 do `Firebase` `(firebase-auth)`. 
Estou a tentar chamar o metodo `sendEmailVerification()` da seguinte forma:

```
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();

    user.sendEmailVerification()
```

Alguém sabe porque me está a acontecer isto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso acontece porque o método `sendEmailVerificado` foi adicionado no Firebase somente a partir do [SDK Version 9.6](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#9.6) de 21 de Setembro 2016 e você está usando o `9.0.2`. Por esse motivo, não é possível reconhecido o método.

Para mais detalhes, veja [aqui](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/) as notas de atualizações do Firebase.